# Error in Text Views line breaks? In android studio 2.2

Tags: android

I have developed an application in android . In my mobile (Samsung galaxy grand2 with Kitkat 4.4.2) all the `textViews` are looking fine but In some of the mobile the texts are divided into 2 lines.

Comment: Provided the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: Don't suggest to use deprecated properties like `android:singleLine="true"`. Check Dheerubhai Bansal's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 add  android:maxLines="1" in Textview XML
```

Answer (score 0):

set your textView as

```
android:maxLines = "1"
```

Comment: `singleLine ` deprecated

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks for pointing  out that i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your Xml

```
android:inputType="textMultiline"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Based on the text alignment

```
android:gravity="left" or  android:gravity="right" or      android:gravity="center"
```